# Receive Intent when email received

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to get a notificiation in my app when a new email arrives? It's for the gmail adresses on the phone. In my app I want to notifiy the user that a new email has arrived. Is there an Intent I can listen to in the default mail app?

Or do I have to use an app like https://k9mail.github.io/documentation/development/intents.html K9 Mail which offers me intents?

Comment: There is no single "default mail app" in Android. There are ~2 billion devices spread across ~10,000 device models. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of email client apps. The user can be using any of those. Few, if any, will offer an API to allow third-party apps to know when mail arrives.

Comment: I have an app for my company only, so I actually just have the default android app for gmail, not a special app. I was wondering if there is an intent I can listen to, if a new gmail email arrives. When not, I will use K9 Mail